# Как сделать смену спрайта в юнити 2д при рахработке Top Down рогалика

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Есть несколько позиций персонажа,хочу что б при нажатии кнопки влево его спрайт менялся на поворот влево и тд , может кто подскажет?

Comment: если Вам помог ответ, то отметьте его как правильный и закройте тему

Answer (score 2):

Вешаете скрипт на персонажа:

```
    public Sprite[] States; // Состояния персонажа

    // Этот метод вешаете на нужную вам кнопку и выставляете соответствующий индекс
    public void Change(int stateIndex)
    {
       GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = States[stateIndex];
    }
```

Если в вашем списке спрайт для состояний влево является 0м элементом, то для кнопки влево нужно ставить 0:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]